# knockoutjs 'optionsValue' doesn't work

Tags: knockout.js

I have a code that doesn't work.
This is here http://jsfiddle.net/JPBarbosa/uxwTM/4/.

The data bind parameter **optionsValue** doesn't work like parameter **optionsText**.

I'm using the same function for both!

```
<select data-bind="options: times, optionsText: function(item) { return item.toLocaleTimeString(); }, optionsValue: function(item) { return item.toLocaleTimeString(); }, value: selectedTime"></select>
```

Regards, JP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [binding both optionValue and optionText in a select box from arbitrary JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328108/binding-both-optionvalue-and-optiontext-in-a-select-box-from-arbitrary-javascrip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you pass in for `optionsValue` must be a string corresponding to the name of the property to use as a value.  You cannot set it to a value like that, it doesn't work the same way as `optionsText` unfortunately.

It would be easier to map the `times` array to the values you want instead.

```
<select data-bind="options: ko.utils.arrayMap(times(), function (time) { return time.toLocaleTimeString(); }), value: selectedTime"></select>
```

Though you'll want to keep the mapping code out of your view.  So add a computed observable to your view model that returns the mapped values.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    // ...
    self.mappedTimes = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.times(), function (time) {
            return time.toLocaleTimeString();
        });
    })
};
```

```
<select data-bind="options: mappedTimes, value: selectedTime"></select>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/uxwTM/5/)